# Sed: How to replace multiple times per line with wildcard?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, unix, sed

I am using sed to replace patterns in multiple files recursively in a directory. Simple command:

`find . -name '*.md' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "" "s/+++/---/g"`

This one replaces all `+++` with `---` in all files named `*.md`.

---

Now I want to do the same for something with two wildcards in MacOS:

`find . -name '*.md' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "" 's/{{% link "\(.*\)" "\(.*\)" %}}/[\1](\2)/g'`

My desired result would be a string change from

```
{{% link "My Link" "https://example.com" %}}
```

to

```
[My Link](https://example.com)
```

in all files. It **works for one occurrence per line, but not for multiple occurrences. For instance,

```
This {{% link "Link One" "https://domainone.com" %}} and that {{% link "Link Two" "https://domaintwo.com" %}} ...
```

becomes

```
This [Link One" "https://domainone.com" %}} and that {{% link "Link Two" "https://domaintwo.com) ...
```

But I want

```
This [Link One](https://domainone.com) and that [Link Two](https://domaintwo.com) ...
```

How can I fix this behavior? Would be super grateful for your help.

Comment: `'s/{{% link "\([^"]*\)" "\([^"]*\)" %}}/[\1](\2)/g'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are a hero. I searched for this problem a while, but it was difficult to find something with the intersection of multiple occurrences per line + wildcard. I thought I would have to wait for an answer a couple of days, but thanks to you, I can just continue my work. Thank you so much! You made my day :)

Comment: Please submit your comment as answer, so that I can mark it as the solution!

Comment: It is a very common and well-known issue, asked almost every day, I'd prefer to close the question as a duplicate.